# Issues reimplementing some C# encryption stuff in C++ using cryptopp

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, crypto++, pbkdf2

So I have this piece of C# code:

```
void Decrypt(Stream input, Stream output, string password, int bufferSize) {
    using (var algorithm = Aes.Create()) {
        var IV = new byte[16];
        input.Read(IV, 0, 16);
        algorithm.IV = IV;
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, algorithm.IV, 100);
        algorithm.Key = key.GetBytes(16);
        using(var decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor())
        using(var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(input, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
            CopyStream(cryptoStream, output, bufferSize);
        }
    }
}
```

and I am trying to translate this into C++ with CryptoPP.
So this is what I have written:

```
void decrypt(std::ifstream& in_file, std::ofstream& out_file, std::string_view password, size_t bufSize) {
    using namespace CryptoPP;
    // Get IV
    byte iv[16];
    in_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(iv), sizeof(iv));
    // Read cypher
    std::string cypher;
    while (in_file && cypher.size() != bufSize) {
        char c;
        in_file.read(&c, 1);
        cypher.push_back(c);
    }
    // Get key
    byte key[16];
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<SHA1> pbkdf2;
    pbkdf2.DeriveKey(key, sizeof(key), 0, reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(password.data()), password.size(), iv, sizeof(iv), 100);
    // Decrypt
    CTR_Mode<AES>::Decryption decrypt(key, sizeof(key), iv);
    std::string output;
    StringSource(cypher, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(decrypt, new StringSink(output)));
    // Write output to file
    out_file.write(output.data(), output.size());
}
```

However, from this function, I am only getting back trash data. What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks

Tuxifan!

Comment: Default cipher mode for AES in .NET is CBC. Have you tried `CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption`?

Comment: Oh! But this is giving me a:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::InvalidCiphertext'
  what():  StreamTransformationFilter: ciphertext length is not a multiple of block size`

with bufSize == 2048

Comment: The size of your encrypted data should be a multiple of 16 bytes. You could veryfy if `cypher` contains the same data as `input` in C# after reading the first 16 bytes for IV.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35114331/881253

Comment: I double-checked, std::string stores null-terminators since it's got its own length field. I noticed that the file is shorter that the bufferSize tho. How does C# handle that? Since just filling the rest with 0 causes an error (obviously).

Comment: You must read the exact length of your data. A C# stream reads until end of stream. You can then read fileSize - 16 bytes. I don't really know C++ but what I found is a char is a 16 bit value, so you need to read `(fileSizeInBytes - 16) / 2` chars.

Comment: So I need to cut off the rest of the file? But why would the file have such size if the last bytes are going to get cut off anyways?  Btw: a char is 8 bit in C++.

Comment: You shouldn't cut away anything. The C# stream has a `Length`. If you read from the stream, the position is advanced by the number of bytes read. You can read from the stream until you reach the end of the stream. Your file contains the IV in the first 16 bytes. Then you read all bytes until the end. If you have a file size of 1030, then you have 16 bytes IV and 1024 bytes of encrypted data. You should therefore have `bufSize = 1024`. (regarding char: I was asking google and only read the first sentence. My bad.)

Comment: Well, the file I am reading from however has that does not divide by 16 and smaller than the blockSize of 2048 – however the C# code handles that just fine, with blockSize == 2048 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution! First of all, as @mbd mentioned, C# uses CBC by default. Additionally, I need to cut away the rest of the data like this:

```
while ((cipher.size() % 16) != 0) {
    cipher.pop_back();
}
```